# Error in NULLIF()?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

Please have a look at the following code

```
public List<String> getNames()
{
List<String> names = new ArrayList();


try
{
    createConnection();

    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select NULLIF(names,' '),NULLIF(middleName,' '),NULLIF(lastName,' ') from PhoneData order by names asc");

    while(rs.next())
    {
        String fullName = rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3);
        names.add(fullName);
    }

    return names;

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
finally
{
    closeConnection();
}
```

}

I am using Apache Derby, embedded version.

I am retrieving 3 items here, first name, middle name and last name. If any item is null, then I am attempting to fill it with a blank space. But, when I run this and add it into a combobox, I can see it hasn't replaced the null values with a blank space!!! All the null values are displayed as 'null'. For an example,

FirstName = "John", MiddleName="", LastName="Laxter"

As you can see, the MiddleName is null. What I am expecting is

"John Laxter"

What I get is "John null Laxter" !!!. Why is this? Please help! I have not had this issue when I am working with MS SQLServer (then NULLIF is isNull()). What's wrong here? Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(names,' '),...
```

Comment: @RahulTripathi He is always quick :)

Comment: You are a great programmer! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: and please, provide the same answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874251/indexoutofboundsexception-because-of-null-values#comment17430565_12874251. I managed to overcome that as well using this one :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select 
coalesce(names,' '),
coalesce(middleName,' '),
coalesce(lastName,' ') 
from PhoneData
order by names asc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    coalesce(names,' '),
    coalesce(middleName,' '),
    coalesce(lastName,' ') 
from PhoneData 
order by names asc
```

[`nullif()` does not do what you think.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)